# How do we encrypt a file with AES in node http proxy?

Tags: node.js, encryption, proxy

I have created a http proxy in nodejs using `http-proxy` package. What I want to do through this proxy is listen to the request coming to the proxy, encrypt the file contents and forward it to the respective service. So I am using proxyReq event to listen to the request coming to proxy. and trying to encrypt the file in request.

```
const { createEncryptStream, setPassword } = require('aes-encrypt-stream');
const PassThroughStream = require('stream').PassThrough;

proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, pReq, pRes) => {
    setPassword(Buffer.from(pReq.encryptionKey, 'hex'));
    const stream = new PassThroughStream();
    createEncryptStream(pReq).pipe(stream);
});
```

I amnot that good with streams but how do I encrypt the files in request and forward it? I tried various solutions of chunking the file contents incase of multipart/form-data and forwarding it but that use memory extensively. So I am looking for a solution where I can encrypt in the stream.

Comment: Is there a motivation for using a third party lib to do the proxying? Shall the script be executable on a specific legacy version of Node? If not, nodejs already offer standard libraries that covers this scenario. Also, where is the encryption key defined? Is it an HTTP header?

Comment: Yeah. we can use. a third. party library for proxying. It would be good if it. runs in Node version 12. Yeah, encryptionKey is an http header for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of memory usage, the problem with the code you shown here is that the stream will buffer all the incoming data.

Assuming that `targetRequestStream` is the upstream request, and `targetResponseStream` is the upstream response. This will make sure that the data is encrypted and sent to the target server as it is read. And the response is decrypted and sent to the client as it is received.

```js
const { createEncryptStream, setPassword } = require('aes-encrypt-stream');
proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, pReq, pRes) => {
    setPassword(Buffer.from(pReq.encryptionKey, 'hex'));
    createEncryptStream(pReq).pipe(targetRequestStream);
    createDecryptStream(targetResponseStream).pipe(pRes)
});
```

Other way to prevent all the data from buffering is to add add an a `data` event listener.

```js
const { createEncryptStream, setPassword } = require('aes-encrypt-stream');
proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, pReq, pRes) => {
    setPassword(Buffer.from(pReq.encryptionKey, 'hex'));
    createEncryptStream(pReq)
      .on('data', (data) => { /*handle encrypted data here */});
    createDecryptStream(targetResponseStream)
      .on('data', (data) => { /* handle decrypted data here */ });
});
```